# Datagridview Combo Box need Sql Statement

Tags: vb.net

This is Normal Combo Box SQL:

```
Dim sSQL As String = "
    SELECT *
    FROM Setvalue
    WHERE (QtyinPcs = '" & ComboPackage.Text & "')"
```

How can I add SQL for `Datagridview` Combo Box same like Normal Combo Box?

Comment: Have you Googled yet to see? As of right now it seems that you haven't attempted anything.

Comment: There's no such thing as "ComboBox SQL" or "adding SQL for DataGridView ComboBox".  Please describe what you're actually trying to accomplish.